# How to play the same sound overlapping with AVAudioPlayer?

Tags: swift, audio, avaudioplayer, overlap

This code plays the sound when the button is tapped but cancels the previous if it is pressed again. I do not want this to happen I want the same sound to overlap when repeatedly pressed. I believe it might be due to using the same AVAudioPlayer as I have looked on the internet but I am new to swift and want to know how to create a new AVAudioPlayer everytime the method runs so the sounds overlap.

```
   func playSound(sound:String){


    // Set the sound file name & extension

    let soundPath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(sound, ofType: "mp3")!)
    do {
        //Preperation
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
    } catch _{
    }
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    }
    catch _ {
    }
    //Play the sound
    var error:NSError?
    do{
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundPath)
    }catch let error1 as NSError {
        error = error1
    }

   audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
  audioPlayer.play()

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To play two sounds simultaneously with AVAudioPlayer you just have to use a different player for each sound.

In my example I've declared two players, `playerBoom` and `playerCrash`, in the Viewcontroller, and I'm populating them with a sound to play via a function, then trigger the play at once:

```
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var playerBoom:AVAudioPlayer?
    var playerCrash:AVAudioPlayer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        playerBoom = preparePlayerForSound(named: "sound1")
        playerCrash = preparePlayerForSound(named: "sound2")

        playerBoom?.prepareToPlay()
        playerCrash?.prepareToPlay()
        playerBoom?.play()
        playerCrash?.play()

    }

    func preparePlayerForSound(named sound: String) -> AVAudioPlayer? {
        do {
            if let soundPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(sound, ofType: "mp3") {
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
                return try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: soundPath))
            } else {
                print("The file '\(sound).mp3' is not available")
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
        return nil
    }

}
```

It works very well but IMO is not suitable if you have many sounds to play. It's a perfectly valid solution for just a few ones, though.

*This example is with two different sounds but of course the idea is exactly the same for two identic sounds.*

Comment: Your answer is good and provides more insight to the issue but what If I don't know the amount of audioPlayers I need in code. Is there a way to declare more "var playerBoom:AVAudioPlayer?" through a looping method? Also is AVAudioPlayer the only way to play sound in swift?

Comment: If you don't know the amount of sounds (btw this is a different issue than your question, which was "play the *same* sound overlapping") then you shouldn't use AVAudioPlayer to solve your issue. Because you have to declare one player and variable for each sound, there's no choice if you want overlapping: AVAudioPlayer can only play one sound at a time. Well, you could create an *array* of AVAudioPlayers prepared with sounds, and hold the array in one variable, but I don't recommend this kind of solution it's quickly messy. You will have to look for other methods than AVAudioPlayer, I'm afraid.

Comment: I mean it is one sound but who knows how many times it can be played relative to length of the sound file and times pressed. (could be 10 or 100 overlapping of the same sound) Have you ever used another way to play sound? Thank you for your answer anyways, it was prompt and thorough

Comment: Thanks. Well if there is only one sound, my answer applies. Just give the same sound to the two AVAudioPlayers and play them alternatively as many times as you need. But this is not ideal because not precise and I don't recommend it. Have a look at SpriteKit sound methods I guess it will be more suited for your needs.

Comment: With the alternating method do you know how to create an array of AVAudioPlayers because I might be using alot of audio players.

Comment: You can play sounds with the AVPlayer instead. It has more functionality and is a more precise player than AVAudioPlayer. You can use AVQueuePlayer, a subclass of AVPlayer, to load an array of sounds into the queue. I have not tried to use it to play overlapping sounds but I think there is a way

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a solution using just AVAudioPlayer.

Instead, I have found a solution to this problem with a library that is built on top of AVAudioPlayer.

The library allows same sounds to be played overlapped with each other.

https://github.com/adamcichy/SwiftySound