# call can throw error message Swift 2

Tags: error-handling, swift2

I just converted my app to Swift 2, and of course, am getting one error message:

"Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the eror is not handled"

I did search here for how to fix this, but the answers are even more confusing to me than the error itself. LOL.

My application worked perfectly until I converted it into Swift 2. Wonderful...

```
var myPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

var yourSound1 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("RemSound_01", ofType: "wav")!)
func initYourSound() {
    myPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: yourSound1, fileTypeHint: nil)
    myPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    myPlayer.volume = 1.0 // < for setting initial volume, still not perfected.
}
```

The error throws in the following line:

myPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: yourSound1, fileTypeHint: nil)

How am I supposed to fix this? I understand that Swift is trying to "universalize" error handling, but doing so by breaking even the simplest of code seems silly to me.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Use Do-Try-Catch. An simple example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34767908/2227743

Comment: I will try your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Note that the docs for that method now say, "You call this method in a try expression and handle any errors in the catch clauses of a do statement, as described in Error Handling in The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2.1)".

Comment: I tried as best I could, and ended up with a lot more errors. From one error to like 6 or 7. I'll try something else tomorrow I guess.

Comment: I guess I have to go and read Swift 2.1 and relearn this. SO much for expediency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the pattern you are looking for.

```
<throwing function> // compiler error in Swift 2    
do { try <throwing function> } catch { }
```

In catch you usually get an error that you can handle further.

Answer (score 0):

This works in Swift 2.0, put it in your viewDidLoad method ...

```
do {
        try AudioPlayer  = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: ButtonAudioURL, fileTypeHint: nil)
    } catch {
        print("errorin do-try-catch")
    }
```

where `ButtonAudioURL` is

```
  var ButtonAudioURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Besides", ofType: "mp3")!)
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Here Is how I modified my code snippet:


func initYourSound() {
        do {
            try myPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: shotgunSound, fileTypeHint: nil)
        myPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        myPlayer.volume = 1.0 // < for setting initial volume, still not perfected. 
        } catch {
            // handle error
        }

Comment: I was able to compile, but now I get this error: SIGABRT. in line 1 of my AppDelegate swift file:

2016-01-25 08:51:52.395 WarningShot1.0.0[277:13379] -[WarningShot1_0_0.ViewController playMySound:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x154e4f7c0
2016-01-25 08:51:52.397 WarningShot1.0.0[277:13379] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[WarningShot1_0_0.ViewController playMySound:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x154e4f7c0'

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: You will have to add more code so we can see what is causing that issue. Open up a new question for that

Comment: Thanks, I did ask a new question for this, hopefully with enough code to have an idea of what is happening.