# Create a sound button that can be pressed multiple times

Tags: ios, swift, audio, swift3, uibutton

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AudioToolbox

var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

    var player: AVAudioPlayer?
    let soundFiles = ["Roblox", "RobloxDistort", "Cringe"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }


    @IBAction func soundPlayer(_ sender: UIButton) {
        playSound(fileName: soundFiles[0])

    }

    func playSound(fileName: String) {

        let soundUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "mp3")

        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundUrl!)
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }

        audioPlayer.play()

    }

}
```

Hello, I am fairly new to swift and am making a simple soundboard app for my friends and I. Currently, I have a button that plays the correct sound, but only once. If I press it multiple times quickly, it just stops the sound and then plays it once again.

I want to get the button to be "spammable." If I press it quickly, I want it to play the sound for each one of those presses, and for those sounds to overlap.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to play the same sound overlapping with AVAudioPlayer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34764007/how-to-play-the-same-sound-overlapping-with-avaudioplayer)

Comment: You may want to use a different word than "spammable" - that can be translated into some *very* different (and not as accurate) meanings. Also, looking at the link @the4kman provided, you may need to explain exactly what you want - if a user tapped your `UIButton` three times in quick succession, do you wish to hear the same sound in (it's entirety) three times? Or interrupt the currently playing sounds for a new instance? A detail like that may mean quite a bit to a good answer.